# How to evaluate $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \alpha^k \binom{n}{k}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to show that the function that satisfies $f^\prime(x)=f(x)$ with $f(0)=1$ behaves in an exponential way (in other words, I want to justify writing it as $e^x$). I need to show that:
$$
f(a)f(b) =f(a+b).
$$
We have:
$$
f(a)f(b) = \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{a^k}{k!} \right)\left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{b^k}{k!} \right),
$$
and using a [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product),  $ f(a)f(b) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n $ where:

$$
c_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac{a^k}{k!} \dfrac{b^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}
    = \dfrac{b^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left[\dfrac{a}{b}\right]^k \binom{n}{k}.
$$

I am stuck here, because I do not know how to evaluate the sum with the binomial coefficient that includes a power of $k$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you heard of the [Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Oh my that was stupid, I should go to bed. Thank you.

Comment: Surely you could just solve it as a differential equation to get $e^x$? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @EulCan You can if you assume that you know what $e^x$ is. What I'm doing is showing that $e^x$ is indeed an exponential function. Starting from "a function whose derivative is equal to its value at every point", I obtain a Taylor series for that function. Then I show that it behaves analogously to exponentiation on $\mathbb{Z}$, and thus use it to *define* exponentiation on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MGA Ah I gotcha. Perhaps I should go to bed too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [Binomial Theorem,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) the sum from $k=0$ to $n$ is $(1+\alpha)^n$.

Comment: Thanks @AndréNicolas. Actually I meant from $k=0$ in the title, it was a typo. It is in fact **exactly** the binomial theorem, I can't believe I missed it. Off to bed. :)

Comment: Recognition would be instant if it were $\alpha^k\beta^{n-k}$. But the "missing" $1^{n-k}$ makes it less obvious.